# wait till the previous function executes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, wait

so here are my functions

```
$scope.addToCartReturn = null;

$scope.addToCart = function() {
    $scope.addToCartReturn = false;
    $scope.cartProduct = {};
    angular.extend($scope.cartProduct, {
        "id" : $scope.product.dealDtoId
    }, {
        "optionsDto" : $scope.product.optionsDto
    }, {
        "qty" : 1
    });
    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'cart/addtocart',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data : $scope.cartProduct
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (data.string == "sucess") {
            alert("Sucessfully Added to Cart");
            $scope.addToCartReturn = true;
        }
    });
};

$scope.buyNow = function() {
    $scope.addToCart();
    if ($scope.addToCartReturn = true) {
        $state.go("App.Cart");
    } else {
        alert("Error Please Wait");
    }
};
```

what's actually happening is, when i call buynow function, the addtocart function is called. and before it finishes, the other lines are getting executed.

so my doubt is how to make it wait till that addtocart function is over.

and each function may be called separately so, i want the addtocart function also to alert a value on success

and now i am using a addtocartreturn scope variable to know the status, what is a better way to do this. such as returning a variable.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

`$http` returns a promise, you can wait for execution by using a `.then()` like so:

```
$scope.addToCart = function() {
    return $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'cart/addtocart',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        data : $scope.cartProduct
    })
};

$scope.buyNow = function() {
    $scope.addToCart()
        .then(function() {
            // Success function
            $state.go("App.Cart");
        }, function() {
            // Error function
            alert("An error occured !");
        })
};
```

More info about promises and `$q` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but i want each function to have alerts individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either callbacks or promises. Promises are already explained by martijn. See Callbacks

```
var callBack = function(){
 if ($scope.addToCartReturn = true) {
    $state.go("App.Cart");
 } else {
    alert("Error Please Wait");
 }
}
$scope.addToCart(callBack);
```

Change definition

```
    $scope.addToCart = function(callBack) {
```

Then call the callback in success

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but i want each function to have alerts individually.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` is a asynchronous function, hence it would proceed with next statement in script, one way to execute the things which need to be processed after `addToCart` is executed can be done as below.

Pass a `callback` function as a function reference and execute it on successful call of ajax request.

```
 $scope.addToCart = function(successHandler,errorHandler) {
   $http({
     method : 'POST',
     url : 'cart/addtocart',
     headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
     },
     data : $scope.cartProduct
   }).then(
    successHandler,errorHandler // this will trigger the respective callbacks
  );
}; 

$scope.buyNow = function() {
  $scope.addToCart(successCallback);
};

function successCallback(successRes) {
    //add all the stuff here post "addToCart" processing
    $state.go("App.Cart");
}

function errorCallback(errorRes) {
   //handle error response here
}
```

**Note**:

- As mentioned by @charlietfl, replace `.success` with `then`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- try to handle error responses as well returned from remote server[This is as important as handling successful responses]
- Before triggering ajax call try showing a loading icon to user and remove it once response is received from remote server, this way your page would be interacting & would not look stale.

Comment: `success` is deprecated ... use promise instead per `$http` docs

Comment: @charlietfl: missed that completely :P

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but i want each function to have alerts individually.

Comment: you mean you want to alert user after succesfully adding item to cart ?

Answer (score -1):

use Deferred and Promise explained here
[click here](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/deferred-and-promise.html)

Comment: An answer that only provides a link is of very little value especially when that link rots in the future. Links should only be used to support the code in the answer itself

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but i want each function to have alerts individually.